# How to make app calling without bringing it to the foreground in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

When 2 iOS apps are in the background, can we make app to app calling without bringing them to the foreground? E.g., passing data/instructions from one app to the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server as a backend to both apps and use notifications to notify the user for the new changes.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what we are doing right now—wondering if there is any other way of doing it.